# Library or code to convert digit in letters

Tags: digits, letters

Could you suggest me a code or a library (possibly java) to convert digits (e.g. 24) in letters (e.g. twenty-four)? Obviously I need to change locale (from English to Italian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3685
You'll have to translate the numbers into italian, but apart from that it should solve your problem.

/Klaus

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately the Italian language is very difficult. I don't need only to translate the  numbers because the rules to combining them can change depending on the first or the last letter fo the number. However, this is a good starting point.
Thank you,
Fabio